# htaccess file not working windows 7 using wamp

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

I'm running WAMP on my Win7 box and trying to configure an htaccess folder to restrict my guests from browsing the directory structure.

Right now, if you head to, it will list the directory structure which I do not want. They should be only able to get to the .html site.

I've already modified the httpd.conf file to remove the commented out rewrite mod.

I've added the htaccess file to the documentroot of my website.

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
options -indexes
# or #
IndexIgnore *
```

I've restarted all services multiple times.
Should the htaccess be in the WWW folder or the document root? I run many websites virtually and only care about my main site, so I've been placing the htaccess inside that folder, but have tried www as well.

Comment: The directory should inherit `.htaccess` from parent, but for testing, have you tried adding the `.htaccess` file to your `/Technical` directory?

Comment: iv tried added it to the directory itself with no change.  Now i gave my htaccess a name......  gts.htaccess  It has to have a filename, right?

Comment: sometimes a sprinkle my folders with a dummy index.php as can be seen here http://mathpdq.com/api/

Comment: http://funk.randomecho.com/soul/wamp-setup-and-configuration-tips.php

Comment: Drew that sounds doable, i like that option.  htaccess would have been easier though.  Argh!

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you've edited the proper .htaccess file in the website's DocumentRoot folder.

```
Options -Indexes
```

The above will only work if your particular WAMP's configuration and the website's VirtualHost file has the proper AllowOverride value set, such as...

```
AllowOverride All
```

Check the website's VirtualHost file, and/or httpd.conf's for something like...

```
<Directory "C:/WampDeveloper/Websites/www.example.com/webroot">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

If it's not set to `All` nor lists `Indexes`, that .htaccess line is going to get ignored.

> I've already modified the httpd.conf file to remove the commented out rewrite mod

mod_rewrite has nothing to do with this.

> I've restarted all services multiple times.

.htaccess files are re-read on every request. You don't need to restart Apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride